# Simple MVC 3.0 Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an MVC 3.0 Routing problem. I have the following in a CheckListController class:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  //poop
  return View("ChecklistControl");
}
```

Then, in the AreaRegistration.cs that houses that controller, i have the following:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
    "CommonControls_defaultWithId",
    "CommonControls/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = 0 }
    );
    context.MapRoute(
        "CommonControls_default",
        "CommonControls/{controller}/{action}",
        new { action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

However, when i try to browse to it via http://localhost:2064/CommonControls/Checklist/1

i get a 404 error, even though i have that route registered.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL that matches that rout is http://localhost:2064/CommonControls/Checklist/Index/1

What I think you want is

```
context.MapRoute(
    "CommonControls_defaultWithId",
    "CommonControls/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = 0 }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The two Routes seems the same. Remove the latter one and try again.

Comment: i had only the first one to begin with, it had the same issue.